# Form needs to be submitted twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am trying to implement a super simple, super primitive authentication page for my website. The user sees just a single input field and a submit button. If the input matches the password (hashing remains to be added) the user is authenticated.

The problem is, however, that you always have to input the correct string and press the submit button twice. I don't know why this is happening, and it is obviously quite annoying.

Is there any solution for this? All I've found is to use e.preventDefault(), which I am already using, but to no avail.

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import App from '../App'

export default function Password() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false)
  const [pass, setPass] = useState("")
  const secret = ""

  const handleChange = e => {
    setPass(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if (pass === secret) {
      setAuth(true)
    }
  }

  if (auth) {
    return (
      <App/>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input style={{ border: "1px solid grey", borderRadius: "4px" }} type="text" value={pass} onChange={handleChange} />
        <input style={{ border: "1px solid grey", borderRadius: "4px" }} type="submit" value="submit" />
      </form>
    )
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Why are the HTML form elements generated by JavaScript? Typically, those elements are posted with the page load. JavaScript could do some basic validation on the browser client, but the submitted response should be processed by the web server for user authentication.

Comment: Nothing in your frontend is secret. Your users can read it all, even the value in `secret`.